# NFT URL on the blockchain

Tags: nft

Let's say I want to buy BAYC ape #9055 and I want to verify on the blockchain that it looks like as it was advertised.

I go to etherscan
https://etherscan.io/token/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d?a=9055#inventory
and I can see the image there.

But where does this URL come from?
https://storage.googleapis.com/nftimagebucket/tokens/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d/9055.png is the URL, but why this? Who and where defined in the blockchain that the "nftimagebucket" is the correct bucketname?

Querying the smart contract 0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d "tokenURI" function I get ipfs://QmeSjSinHpPnmXmspMjwiXyN6zS4E9zccariGR3jxcaWtq/9055 - but this is not a picture.

Checking https://etherscan.io/nft/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d/9055 there is no official URL ...

Comment: Mea culpa, the ipfs link has an image tag with correct content. 
ipfs://QmTHcV6mGxHGeeXCnYtV129eRiR8Exni4sT8dDikBWBgzY 
What I still don't understand is why is etherscan linking to the googleapis storage?

Comment: It is likely to enhace user experience, not every browser supports the ipfs protocol.

Comment: The issue is not with the IPFS protocol, I can use both an IPFS gateway and the desktop client